# How does it convert _bstr_t to BSTR when passing as an argument?

Tags: visual-c++, smart-pointers, variant, bstr

Taking a simple example:

```
_bstr_t smartString(L"MyString");

Process(smartString); // takes BSTR.
```

Initially I thought _bstr_t has a BSTR operator converting from _bstr_t to BSTR, but looking at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx) there is no such operator defined.

How does it work when passign _bstr_t to BSTR parameter or _variant_t to VARIANT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BSTR` is `typedef`ed to be `WCHAR*` (wtypes.h file) and the latter is `typedef`ed to be `wchar_t*` (winnt.h file) and `_bstr_t` has [`operator wchar_t*()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb.aspx) member variable. So the compiler just uses that operator for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to call a method that expects BSTR*. There is no implicit conversion. Instead, use the GetAddress() parameter for the conversion.

```
void foo( BSTR* ) {...}

void f()
{
   _bstr_t myBstr;
   foo( myBstr.GetAddress() );
}
```